# setAnchorView not working with Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, anchor-view

I am trying to build a music player.

I did everything what is required and the working is smooth but however i can't seem to see my `MediaController` Controls.

**Declaration:**`private MusicController musicController;`

```
public class MusicController extends MediaController {
    public MusicController(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
musicController.setMediaPlayer(this);
musicController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view));
musicController.setEnabled(true);
```

**mainactivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF330000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_parent_view"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I have added a screenshot.

What could be the problem here?

[MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/QQPtQfFM)

[MusicService.java](https://pastebin.com/dU7i9mx3)

[MusicController.java](https://pastebin.com/FzCMkTin)

[MyAdaptor.java](https://pastebin.com/T6CLLndY)

I have included every file that might be important. Please help me look out the problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I see `musicController.show(0);` being called only after some click events.
Should you call it also soon after having set the anchorView?

From documentation

> void show (int timeout)
>
> Show the controller on screen. It will go away automatically after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.

Try just `musicController.show();`

**EDIT**

I saw you overrode the `MusicController.hide()` method so it shouldn't be removed after the timeout period, but still it seems to me you don't show it when you set the anchorView

**UPDATE**

```
musicController.setMediaPlayer(this);
musicController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view));
musicController.setEnabled(true);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            musicController.show();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

I ran your code and I was able to show the controller after applying a delay. Maybe you should show it after your service is connected...not sure about this, but at least you could try this code and then improve it.

Comment: if you called show(0), it will show the Media Controller until hide() is called.

Comment: and for the first part.No.

Comment: I edited the answer since I did some new tries. Have a look if it can help

Comment: I noticed that the musicController.show() needs to be called, but if you call it without any delay, the application crashes. Did you try it? Does it help?

Comment: yes without any delay , it gets crashed , let me try your answer

Comment: actually i can see two media controllers now. One is present , just below it, try looking at it.
Why is this? Double controller?

Comment: `setEnabled` line does the same, that is why it shows me two controllers. The way you are trying me to do isn't the actual solution, it just puts up one more controller which won;t respond if i select some song

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry it didn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160802/discussion-between-botjr-and-roberto-martucci).